# Creating a dynamic string with bindAttr

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'd like to create a dynamic classname on an object with a value I'm getting from my model. One of the keys is named `provider` which contains either "twitter" or "facebook". What I'd like to do is to prepend the string "icon-" to the provider so that the resulting class is `icon-twitter` or `icon-facebook`.

This is the code that I've got now.

`<i {{bindAttr class=":avatar-icon account.provider"}}></i>`

Ember offers a way to include a static string within the attribute by prepending `:` to it. You can see that I'm also adding a class called `avatar-icon` in this example. I've already tried `:icon-account.provider` which simply resulted in the literal string "icon-account.provider".

**RESPONSE**
Nice one. I'm working on a solution similar to your answer right now. Question though: this view will be used within the context of an each loop. How would I pass in the current item to be used within the view? I have this right now:

`{{#each account in controller}}
    {{#view "Social.AccountButtonView"}}
        <i {{bindAttr class="account.provider"}}></i>
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}`

Is it possible to just do this:

`{{#view "Social.AccountButtonView" account="account"}}`

?

Comment: I believe you'd have to do something like `{{#view "Social.AccountButtonView" accountBinding="account"}} <i>...</i> {{/view}}`. I believe `account` would be out of scope from within the child view in this case, so from within the view, you'd refer to this as `view.account`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have previously stated that `attributeBindings` would be a suitable solution for this, but I was mistaken. When binding the `class` attribute of a given `View`, as pointed out, you should use `classNames` or `classNameBindings`. Please refer to the sample below:

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
    provider: 'Facebook',
    classNameBindings: 'providerClass',
    providerClass: function() {
        return 'icon-avatar icon-%@'.fmt(this.get('provider').toLowerCase());
    }.property('provider')
});
```

This will render the following HTML:

```
<div id="ember212" class="ember-view icon-avatar icon-facebook">
    <h1>App</h1>    
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/HH9Sk/**

(Note: The fiddle is linking to a version of Ember.js earlier than RC)

Comment: You shouldn't advertise using `attributeBindings`, you should just use `classNameBindings`. I fear they'll commonly conflict.

Comment: @ebryn could you explain a little more? Honest question: What do you mean when you say they will commonly conflict?

Comment: If you want to update the `class` attribute, you should use the `classNames` or `classNameBindings` properties exposed in `Ember.View`. I believe using `attributeBindings: ['class']` is a bad idea when these features already exist.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean in the sense that it's up to the developer to include "ember-view" in the `class` attribute using `attributeBindings`. Just so I get a better understanding, when would it be considered OK to use `attributeBindings`?

Comment: Use `attributeBindings` for any attribute other than `class`.