# ember version 1.6.1 best to way to bind css style

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember version 1.6.1. I would like to show an error message if user doest not enter username and password correctly. I think i have to use bind-style. now I have code like this:

```
  <fieldset class="error-message" {{bind-style visibility="isVisible:visible:hidden"}}>
          <span>invalid username/password</span>
   </fieldset>
```

what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Handlebars supports dynamic class binding exceptionally better than it does style binding. To do that you'd bind-attr to the class.  http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/

#### Css

```
.visible{
  visibility:visible;
}

.hidden{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

#### Handlebars

```
<fieldset {{bind-attr class=":error-message isVisible:visible:hidden"}}>
      <span>invalid username/password</span>
</fieldset>
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/didax/1/edit

You can bind-attr the style property and create a computed property that returns the raw style text `visibility:visible`, but that's ugly and not necessary in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Although class is generally the best way to set these visual changes, consider using [classNameBindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076634/creating-a-dynamic-string-with-bindattr/15077116#15077116) instead of bind-attr. That would require you to create a `View` class.

However, the best way to bind element *attributes* that don't have a specific binding mechanism, would be via `attributeBindings`:

(this approach also needs a `View` class)

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['style'],
  style: function() {
    return 'color: #F00';
  }.property()
});
```

This is way is a little better because you can watch the `style` property of your view class and it will automatically bind to your view markup. And since that is a computed property, you can create your own code to determine changes of other attributes in your view that could cause the style attribute to be reconstructed, and again, automatically bound to your view.

You could have a property that the `style` property watches with `property('dependency')`, so when it changes, `style` is once again computed and the view is updated. For example, let's say that you have a view which is a custom input box with built-in validation. You have a property `valid` which returns `boolean`, being `true` for valid and `false` for invalid values.

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['style'],
  valid: function() {
     return false;
  }.property(),
  style: function() {
     // these variables and all should ideally be somewhere else,
     // as color codes could potentially be global for the app
     var _invalidColor = "#F00";
     var _validColor= "#000";
     if (this.get('valid')) {
         return 'color: ' + _validColor + ';';
     } else {
         return 'color: ' + _invalidColor + ';';
     }
  }.property('valid')
});
```

(see [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuseyiqozevo/1/edit))

Keep in mind this is a crude example to show the functionality/possibilities. Manually change the return value of `valid` property of the `IndexView` in JS Bin to see how it affects the view template.